# I can't stop Windows 10 from compressing files when I download

Tags: windows-10, download, compression, file-download

I can't stop Windows 10 from compressing files upon download. I have gone into the command line (right click and run as administrator) and done

```
fsutil behavior set disableCompression
```

and then rebooted. I've gone back to check to make sure it is set and done:

```
fsutil behavior query disableCompression
```

and have received the message

```
disabledCompression = 1 (Enabled)
```

which I assume means the disabling is enabled.

I have also made sure the download folder itself in the Advanced section of the General tab does not have the 'Compress contents to save disk space' box checked. (It is unchecked)

And yet, when I download something it still automatically compresses. Does anyone have a solution to this? Thank you.

ETA:  The reason I know they are compressed is when I download them, they appear with the 2 blue arrows pointing at each other in the top right corner. To get the blue arrows to go away, I have to right click on the file, and uncheck the "Compress contents..." box in the Advanced section of the General tab.

Comment: Please explain how you have confirmed the files are being compressed automatically.

Comment: Download *how*? puTTY? Firefox? Windows FTP? Have you tried alternatives??

Comment: This is if I download via a web browser.

Comment: Is compression enabled on the drive/partition? If so, is there a reason compression is enabled on the drive/partition but you don't want the files compressed? Why do you not want compression? What folder(s) are these files being downloaded to?